# jQuery Change all input data at same time

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-5

I am using https://shaack.com/projekte/bootstrap-input-spinner/ for that one and i try to change all input values when anybody changes (by doing with input class .ppom-quantity).

For example, if the value of the third is written 5, the value of the others should be 5 aswell and All the + and - should affect them all.

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8bayz3dn/

`

```js
 $("input[type='number']").inputSpinner()
```

```html
<link href="https://shaack.com/projekte/bootstrap-input-spinner/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://shaack.com/projekte/bootstrap-input-spinner/src/input-spinner.js"></script>
<script src="https://shaack.com/projekte/bootstrap-input-spinner/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">


<div class="row my-2">
    <div class="col-4 text-start">
        <label>First</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
       <input type="number" inputmode="decimal" value="1" class="form-control ppom-quantity text-center">
    </div>
</div>
 
<div class="row my-2">
  <div class="col-4 text-start">
    <label>Second</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8">
    <input type="number" inputmode="decimal" value="1" class="form-control ppom-quantity text-center">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row my-2">
  <div class="col-4 text-start">
    <label>Third</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8">
    <input type="number" inputmode="decimal" value="1" class="form-control ppom-quantity text-center">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row my-2">
  <div class="col-4 text-start">
    <label>Fourth</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8">
    <input type="number" inputmode="decimal" value="1" class="form-control ppom-quantity text-center">
  </div>
</div>


</div>
```

`

I would be glad if you could help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an event listener that listens for the `change` and `input` events on your inputs.

```js
//$("input[type='number']").inputSpinner()


$( 'input' ).on( 'change input', function() {
  
  $( 'input').val( $( this ).val() );
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://shaack.com/projekte/bootstrap-input-spinner/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://shaack.com/projekte/bootstrap-input-spinner/src/input-spinner.js"></script>
<script src="https://shaack.com/projekte/bootstrap-input-spinner/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">


<div class="row my-2">
    <div class="col-4 text-start">
        <label>First</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
       <input type="number" inputmode="decimal" value="1" class="form-control ppom-quantity text-center">
    </div>
</div>
 
<div class="row my-2">
  <div class="col-4 text-start">
    <label>Second</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8">
    <input type="number" inputmode="decimal" value="1" class="form-control ppom-quantity text-center">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row my-2">
  <div class="col-4 text-start">
    <label>Third</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8">
    <input type="number" inputmode="decimal" value="1" class="form-control ppom-quantity text-center">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row my-2">
  <div class="col-4 text-start">
    <label>Fourth</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8">
    <input type="number" inputmode="decimal" value="1" class="form-control ppom-quantity text-center">
  </div>
</div>


</div>
```

Comment: Due to documentation of the plugin will also need to use input event as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input[type='number']").on('input', function() {
    $('.ppom-quantity').val($(this).val());
  });
```